# Changing the caption font and line spacing at the same time

Tags: captions, fontsize, line-spacing

I am currently trying to change the font size as well as the line spacing within the captions of my document and am attempting this by using the setspace and caption packages. As the line spacing as well as font size belong to the same setting (font=...) i'm unsure how to set both values.
This code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}

\begin{document}
some text 
\end{document}
```

As well as this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\captionsetup{font={stretch=1.0}}

\begin{document}
some text 
\end{document}
```

Both work individually but i can't manage to set my font as stretch=1.0 as well as footnotesize. For reference, my normal text size is 12 pt and the line spacing is 1.5pt and i would like my caption font to be size 10pt (footnotesize) and have a line spacing of 1.0pt.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can probably use a comma separated list, like `\captionsetup{font={stretch=1.0, footnotesize}}`

Comment: Your claim that "my normal text size is 12pt and the line spacing is 1.5pt" doesn't sound correct. Given that (a) you run `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} ` and (b) the normal baselineskip for a 12pt Roman (aka serif) font is 14.4pt (20% more than the nominal font size), I'd say that the distance between successive lines of text is 21.6pt, not 1.5pt.

Comment: I thought that `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}` would set my line spacing to 1.5. Thanks for pointing this out, i will try and correct this by using the actual baselineskip command.

Comment: Setting the line spacing factor to 1.5 is not the same as having a baselineskip of `1.5pt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in @Jasper Habicht comment, you can write:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[font={small,stretch=1}, labelfont=bf]{caption} % <---
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} 

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\rule{\linewidth}{4pt}
    \caption{\lipsum[1][1-2]}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum[67]
\end{document}
```

For details and all possibilities see `caption` package documentation.

[image]

Comment: If the main document font size is 12pt, the `onehalfspacing` option amounts to setting `\setstretch {1.241}`, *not* `\setstretch{1.5}` (which is what the OP gets by running `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}`). Also, `\usepackage[font={small,...}]{caption}` will result in a font size of 11pt, not 10pt -- which is what the OP said is required.

Comment: A modified version of this fixed my issues: First i thought that using \baselinestretch would set the genereal line spacing, which it doesn't so now i use `\usepackage{setspace} \setstretch{1.5}` as well as `\usepackage[font={footnotesize,stretch=1.0}, labelfont=bf]{caption}` which gives me my 10pt font size as well as the 1.0 line spacing.

Comment: @Charlotte - If you employ the `setspace` package and run `\setstretch{1.5}`, there's no need for setting `stretch=1.0` as one of the `font` options of the `caption` package.

Answer (score 2):

Executing the low-level command

```
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
```

in the preamble is almost always a mistake, as doing so also affects the line spacing in captions, tabular-like environments, and footnotes, which are generally supposed to be typeset single-spaced regardless of the line-spacing that's applied to the other parts of the document.

What to do? Since you load the `setspace` package anyway, I would like to suggest that you run

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
```

That way, you won't have to fiddle with the line spacing in captions.

Your main document font size is set to 12pt. To get the font size that's used in captions to equal `10pt`, it suffices to run

```
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
```